# How to insert date,boolean filed value in apache hive?

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

This is my sample dataset.

```
#cust_id,  #cust_name, #odr_date,#shipdt,#Courer,#recvd_dt,#returned or not,#returned dt,#reson of return
GGYZ333519YS,Allison,01-01-2017,03-01-2017,Fedx,06-01-2017,**no**,null,null
GGYZ333519YS,Allison,08-01-2017,10-01-2017,Delhivery,13-01-2017,**yes**,15-01-2017,Damaged Item
```

And created table structure.

```
create table order
( 
cust_id string,
cust_name string,
order_date date,
ship_date date,
courier_name string,
received_date date,
is_returned boolean,
returned_date date,
reason string
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile;
```

Loading data into the order table using load command. Getting NULL for date fields and boolean fields columun. any idea? how to solve this problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date should be in compatible format 'yyyy-MM-dd' to be inserted into DATE correctly. And BOOLEAN should be one of (TRUE, FALSE).

The solution is to define columns as STRING and convert them during select, or alternatively convert input data before loading into the table.

This is how you can transform data during select if columns defined as STRINGs:

```
select
      from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( returned_date ,'dd-MM-yyyy'), 'dd-MMM-yyyy') as returned_date,
      case when is_returned like '%no%' then false
           when is_returned like '%yes%' then true
           --else will be null by default
       end as is_returned
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Already i loaded the data. i am getting NULL value using select statement .  select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( returned_date ,'MM-dd-yyyy'), 'dd-MMM-yyyy') from order;.

Comment: @LearnHadoop Re-create table with strings instead of DATE and BOOLEAN

Comment: How to insert string format date into date field using insert statment. in oracle we have to_date function. in hive?

Comment: @LearnHadoop The same to_date, if the string is timestamp longer than date. If date string is already in proper format 'yyyy-MM-dd' then no transformation necessary, you can insert it directly into Date. Use solution from my answer to convert date format. String should be in yyyy-MM-dd to be inserted in Date